# Intellij: java: package ... does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have two modules, module1 and module2, in my project.

The module1 depends on modules2, so I have added the module2 to the module1's dependency via the project structure setting.

A problem I am facing is that module2 contains a jar file(namely ojdbc7.jar) from which the module1 is importing classes like

```
import oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP;
      :
```

in its classes.
With this, Intellij can not resolve the importing class.

How should I set IntelliJ or something up to make the class resolved?

Comment: How about adding the jar as a dependency to module1? Dependency management is a very wide field and as far as I remember, imported jar files contents are not exported.

Comment: Actually, I did try that and it worked, but now I am getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" message inseted.